# CrudRepository uses incorrect table/schema for selecting entities

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Recently I started a little project for checking performance with saving entities into a database using different configurations.

I ended up with 3 schemas. Each schema containing 5 tables with same names. When I try to use `CrudRepository#findAll` or `CrudRepository#count` select is generated that selects data from incorrect schema.

Here is the exact commit for my project with test to reproduce the problem https://github.com/hawk1234/spring-boot-db-performance/commit/7176664cfc87ee7d04b84a6d7ef7e4a77d87730a test `IdentityTest#testSave`

e.g. for `CrudRepository#count` i get:

```
select
        count(*) 
    from
        PrimaryTable x */ select
            count(*) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            one_to_one.primary_table primarytab0_
```

When I comment all `PrimaryTable` entities and leave only one from the correct schema (IDENTITY_SCHEMA that is) I will get proper select in the application log

```
select
        count(*) 
    from
        PrimaryTable x */ select
            count(*) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            identity_schema.primary_table primarytab0_
```

Also from what I noticed `CrudRepository#findById` works without any problems. Can anyone tell what is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: I think since your class name "PrimaryTable" is same for each schema, you need to add @Qualifier("beanName") on your entity and repository so that repository can understand to bind with which bean.

Answer (score 0):

Since your *PrimaryTableRepository* is importing *PrimaryTable* (identity)

> import com.mz.example.db.identity.entity.PrimaryTable;

and using it as *Entity (Generic argument)*, the repository will work with *PrimaryTable's definition* i.e schema.

As you previously mentioned, you are commenting any *PrimaryTable* but the one you want to use. You probably got a compilation error and (re)imported the correct class in your *Repository* i.e. one_to_one.

If you are using Eclipse, another possible option if you haven't checked "Build Automatically" under Project tab and you were running an older version or your code.

In my opinion, you won't reach your goal in that way. Spring-Data Repositories works with one and only one entity. You have 5 tables and 3 schemas, so you need 15 repositories and use and Strategy Pattern Design to choose which one repository to use.

Another better option is to specify the schema in the connection string. In that case, you only will need 5 entities and 5 repositories to access your data. I'm not an expert in gradle, but in maven you can replace part of your config using maven-resource-plugin and profiles to set an appropiate connection string.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @bipe15, maybe I wasn't clear with my question. com.mz.example.db.identity.entity.PrimaryTable is the entity I want to use (I want to select data from identity_schema). However for unknown reason repository performs select on one_to_one schema. Also I'm aware I will have to make 15 repositories each one dealing with different entity, just haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 0):

By using the same simple class name you create multiple entities with the same name, which is by default the simple class name. 
Use the `name` attribute of the `@Entity` annotation to give distinct names to all your entities.